# Strange exception by process of writing some App in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm writing one app in ReactJs. I use webpack. When I've tried to start my app, I've got some strange exception which I can't explain at this time:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
  Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cacheable' of undefined
  at module.exports (/Users/rogozindaniil/Documents/sc-react-redux/node_modules/react-hot-loader/index.js:9:11)
  at Function.memoisePluginContainer (/Users/rogozindaniil/Documents/sc-react-redux/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:109:13)
  at Function.normalisePlugin (/Users/rogozindaniil/Documents/sc-react-redux/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:142:32)
  at /Users/rogozindaniil/Documents/sc-react-redux/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:180:30
  at Array.map (native)
  at Function.normalisePlugins (/Users/rogozindaniil/Documents/sc-react-redux/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:154:20)
  at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/rogozindaniil/Documents/sc-react-redux/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:229:36)
  at OptionManager.init (/Users/rogozindaniil/Documents/sc-react-redux/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:374:12)
  at File.initOptions (/Users/rogozindaniil/Documents/sc-react-redux/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:216:65)
  at new File (/Users/rogozindaniil/Documents/sc-react-redux/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:139:24)
```

@ multi main

Comment: Attach your package.json, maybe your index.js too. It is very difficult to help you only with this error. Thanks.

Comment: Try install 3.0.0 or later version of react-hot-roader

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to say without more source code presented, but I would imagine you forgot to use `new` when you added the `hot-loader` module. It should be:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
]
```

Assuming that your error is coming from here: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/blob/master/index.js#L9-L11, the only way I can think that `this` would be `undefined` is if you failed to give it proper context by not using `new`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. There's my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Stream from './components/Stream';

const tracks = [
  {
    title: 'Track 1'
  },
  {
    title: 'Track'
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Stream tracks={tracks} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And there's package.json

```
{
  "name": "Soundcloud-React",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --hot --config ./webpack.config.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2016",
      "react",
      "stage-2"
    ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader",
    "babel"]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  }
}
```